# memory alignment issues with union

Tags: c++, unions, memory-alignment

Is there guarantee, that memory for this object will be properly aligned if we create object of this type in stack?

```
union my_union
{
  int value;
  char bytes[4];
};
```

If we create char bytes[4] in stack and then try to cast it to integer there might be alignment problem. We can avoid that problem by creating it in heap, however, is there such guarantee for union objects? Logically there should be, but I would like to confirm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that depends on what you mean.

If you mean:

> Will both the `int` and `char[4]` members of the union be properly aligned so that I may use them independently of each other?

Then yes. If you mean:

> Will the `int` and `char[4]` members be guaranteed to be aligned to take up the same amount of space, so that I may access individual bytes of the `int` through the `char[4]`?

Then no. This is because `sizeof(int)` is not guaranteed to be 4. If `int`s are 2 bytes, then who knows which two `char` elements will correspond to the `int` in your `union` (the standard doesn't specify)?

If you want to use a union to access the individual bytes of an `int`, use this:

```
union {
  int i;
  char c[sizeof(int)];
};
```

Since each member is the same size, they're guaranteed to occupy the same space. This is what I believe you want to know about, and I hope I've answered it.

Comment: In old C code they used to declare it as `c[0]`. Then access it like normal. Not sure if this is still valid in C++.

Comment: I meant first. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Martin - Probably not, but I'm sure `c[1]` would work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, unions would be utterly useless otherwise.

Comment: Agree. That was my impression too, but it is better to confirm. Thanks :)