# Why aligning of long long union member is bigger than the containing union/struct? Is this correct?

Tags: c++, g++, memory-alignment, unions, unsigned-long-long-int

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496423/memory-alignment-issues-with-union) one could start to believe that alignment of a union is not less than the largest alignment of it's individual members. But I have a problem with the `long long` type in gcc/g++. The full example can be found [here](http://ideone.com/C7Qen), but here are the relevant parts for my question:

```
union ull {
  long long m;
};

struct sll {
  long long m;
};


int main() {
#define pr(v) cout << #v ": " << (v) << endl
   pr(sizeof(long long));
   pr(__alignof__(long long));
   pr(sizeof(ull));
   pr(__alignof__(ull));
   pr(sizeof(sll));
   pr(__alignof__(sll));
};
```

This results in the following output:

```
sizeof(long long): 8
__alignof__(long long): 8
sizeof(ull): 8
__alignof__(ull): 4
sizeof(sll): 8
__alignof__(sll): 4
```

Why is the alignment of a union member bigger than that of the containing union?

**[UPDATE]**

According to Keith's answer **alignof** is wrong here. But I test the following and it seems that **alignof**  tells us the true. See:

```
union ull {
  long long m;
};
long long a;
char b;
long long c;
char d;
ull e;
int main() {
#define pr(v) cout << #v ": " << (v) << endl
   pr(size_t((void*)&b));
   pr(size_t((void*)&c));
   pr(size_t((void*)&d));
   pr(size_t((void*)&e));
   pr(size_t((void*)&c) - size_t((void*)&b));
   pr(size_t((void*)&e) - size_t((void*)&d));
};
```

The output:

```
size_t((void*)&b): 134523840
size_t((void*)&c): 134523848
size_t((void*)&d): 134523856
size_t((void*)&e): 134523860
size_t((void*)&c) - size_t((void*)&b): 8
size_t((void*)&e) - size_t((void*)&d): 4
```

So, the alignment of `long long` is 8 and alignment of union containing `long long` is 4 in global data. For local scope I cannot test this since it seems that compiler is free to rearrange local data - so this trick does not work. Can you comment on this?

**[/UPDATE]**

Comment: I see the same thing on Red Hat, gcc 4.7.0 with `-m32`, but *not* with `-m64` (all `8`s).

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52023 a link to the corresponding gcc bug for _Alignof (C11).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__alignof__` (which is a gcc extension) doesn't necessarily report the *required* alignment for a type.

x86 processors, for example don't really require more than 1-byte alignment for any type. Access to a 4-byte or 8-byte object will likely be more efficient if the object is word-aligned, but byte alignment is sufficient.

Quoting the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Alignment.html#Alignment):

> Some machines never actually require alignment; they allow reference
>   to any data type even at an odd address.  For these machines,
>   `__alignof__` reports the smallest alignment that GCC will give the
>   data type, usually as mandated by the target ABI.

But that still doesn't really answer the question. Even with that loose definition, I can't think of any good reason for `__alignof__` to indicate a stricter alignment for `long long` than for a struct or union containing a `long long`.

A more portable method of determining the alignment of a type is this:

```
#define ALIGNOF(type) ((int)(offsetof(struct {char c; type t;}, t)))
```

This yields the offset of a member of type `t` in a struct consisting of a `char` and a `t`. Using this macro, this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

union ull {
  long long m;
};

struct sll {
  long long m;
};

#define ALIGNOF(type) ((int)(offsetof(struct {char c; type t;}, t)))

int main() {
#define pr(v) std::cout << #v ": " << (v) << std::endl
   pr(sizeof(long long));
   pr(__alignof__(long long));
   pr(ALIGNOF(long long));
   pr(sizeof(ull));
   pr(__alignof__(ull));
   pr(ALIGNOF(ull));
   pr(sizeof(sll));
   pr(__alignof__(sll));
   pr(ALIGNOF(sll));
};
```

produces this output on my system (gcc-4.7, Ubuntu 12.04, x86):

```
sizeof(long long): 8
__alignof__(long long): 8
ALIGNOF(long long): 4
sizeof(ull): 8
__alignof__(ull): 4
ALIGNOF(ull): 4
sizeof(sll): 8
__alignof__(sll): 4
ALIGNOF(sll): 4
```

The results indicated by my `ALIGNOF()` macro are consistent: `long long` has 4-byte alignment, and a struct or union containing a `long long` has 4-byte alignment.

I suspect this is a bug, or at least an inconsistency, in gcc's implementation of `__alignof__`. But the vagueness of the definition makes it hard to be certain that it's really a bug. [It doesn't seem to have been reported](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=alignof).

**Update :**

I may be jumping the gun, but I've just submitted a [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54188).

This [earlier bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10360), closed as "INVALID", is similar, but it doesn't refer to the alignment of the structure itself.

**Update 2 :**

My bug report has been closed as a duplicate of the earlier one. I'll be asking for clarification.

Comment: Thanks much for this `ALIGNOF()` hint.

Comment: However this macro doesn't work for NonPOD types since offsetof does not work with NonPOD (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129894/why-cant-you-use-offsetof-on-non-pod-strucutures-in-c). Do you by chance know solution for NonPOD types?

Comment: can you comment on my update. It seems that `__alignof__(long long)==8` is correct. And what is tested with your `ALIGNOF`is just aligning of `long long` in `struct` which is the same case as my `struct sll { long long m; }`. Maybe this help for your bug report.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: It's tricky; an object that's 8-byte aligned is also 4-byte aligned, so showing that a `long long` object has an 8-byte aligned address doesn't demonstrate that its alignment is 8. But further experiment shows that gcc *does* seem to be aligning `long long` objects at 8-byte boundaries, and `struct { long long x; }` objects at 4-byte boundaries.